# How to pass values of $_GET array to new URL?

Tags: php, html, get

I have a simple form, when the user entered a code and a mobile number, it should open a new url, here is my code:

```
<form method='get'>
ID:     <input type='text' name='code'><br>
Mobile: <input type='text' name='mobile'><br>

<?php

echo "<button type='button' onclick='location.href=\"http://workflow.abfarmarkazi.ir/phpsql/sms_info.php?id={$_GET['code']}&mob={$_GET['mobile']}\"'>Submit</button>";

?>

</form>
```

but the values of `$_GET` array will not updated, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make form to submit on action url directly. after click submit you will redirect on http://workflow.abfarmarkazi.ir/phpsql/sms_info.php?id=text_id&mob=text_mob

```
<form method='get' action ='http://workflow.abfarmarkazi.ir/phpsql/sms_info.php'>
ID:     <input type='text' name='id'><br>
Mobile: <input type='text' name='mob'><br>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: but I should pass $_GET values to end of url, where they appended?

Comment: it's auto add according you want on form submit

Comment: your welcome :) you can accept/upvote helpful answer

Answer (score 2):

If your form should be posted to that URL in the onclick Event on the Button, it cannot work, as the $_GET values are not given in the current file.

Just post the form using the action attribute to the sms_info.php and it should work. For example:

```
<form method='get' action="http://workflow.abfarmarkazi.ir/phpsql/sms_info.php">
ID:     <input type='text' name='code'><br>
Mobile: <input type='text' name='mobile'><br>
<input type="submit" value="SMS">
</form>
```

In your sms_info.php you can access these values via the $_GET superglobal:

```
<?php
// file: sms_info.php

$id = $_GET['code'];
$mob = $_GET['mobile'];

// ...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

K.I.S.S Keep it simple stupid :-)

```
<form method='get' action='http://workflow.abfarmarkazi.ir/phpsql/sms_info.php'>
ID:     <input type='text' name='id'><br>
Mobile: <input type='text' name='mob'><br>
<input type='submit' onclick='this.form.submit();'>Submit</input>
</form>
```

when you click the button it will submit the correct get request to that url.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method='get' action='http://workflow.abfarmarkazi.ir/phpsql/sms_info.php'>
    ID:     <input type='text' name='id'><br>
    Mobile: <input type='text' name='mob'><br>
    <button type='button' onclick='this.form.submit();'>Submit</button>";
    </form>
```

The `$_GET` superglobal is defined as part of the URL string:

```
http://workflow.abfarmarkazi.ir/phpsql/sms_info.php?code=123&mobile=25642356
```

In sms_info.php:

```
echo $_GET['code']; // 123
echo $_GET['Mobile']; // 25642356
```

So `$_GET` is not stored on the server, but is passed with each `HTTP` request, as is `$_POST`, but that is passed in the HTTP headers rather than simply appened to the end of the URL.